# How to implement a custom renderer in Django REST framework for PDF and Excel export?

Tags: django, excel, pdf, django-rest-framework

I have implemented two custom renderers in django rest framework which export data in Excel or PDF format. The problem is that I'm unable to set the file names when the response is generated.

I have the following renderers:

```
# app/renderers.py
import os
import openpyxl
import pdfkit
import random

from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from rest_framework.renderers import BaseRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response

# for newer python, do the configuration for pdfkit
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=r'path_to_bin/wkhtmltopdf')

class XLSXRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    # ... code truncated 

class PDFRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/pdf'
    format = 'pdf'
    charset = 'utf-8'

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        if hasattr(data, 'items'):
            for key, value in data.items():
                if key == 'results':
                    html_string = render_to_string('user_mbe/EmployeeList.html', {'header': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'id_number', 'phone_number', 'email', 'job_title'), 'data': [tuple(x.values()) for x in value]})
                    result = pdfkit.from_string(html_string, output_path=False, configuration=config)

                    return result
        return None
```

```
# app/views.py

from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

from .renderers import PDFRenderer, XLSXRenderer

from .models import Employee
from .serializers.employee import EmployeeSerializer


class EmployeeAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
    # Are these correct here?
    renderer_classes = [PDFRenderer, XLSXRenderer, JSONRenderer]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Employee.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ?? super().get_paginated_response(request, *args, **kwargs)
        ?? unable to set a file name here
        return response
```

Comment: Did you just ask a question and answer it in < 1 min?

Comment: Haha I’ve just never seen this done before is all. Wanted to make sure I wasn’t seeing things

Answer (score 0):

Import the renderers in your views.py and call the superclass' list method to invoke the custom renderer. Once you get the response from your .list method you can add headers for the filename.

```
# app/views.py
# ...

class EmployeeAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
    # The custom renderers go here
    renderer_classes = [PDFRenderer, XLSXRenderer, JSONRenderer]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Employee.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # call .list method here to invoke the relevant renderer
        # based on the request header accept or query param format type
        response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if request.query_params.get("format", "").lower() == 'pdf':
            response.headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=employee_list.pdf'}
        elif request.query_params.get("format", "").lower() == 'xlsx':
            response.headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=employee_list.xlsx'}

        return response
```